# TYPO3 Extbase storagePid

Tags: typo3, extbase

I need to get the actual "general record storage page id". I found the following snipplet but the variable is empty even though the storagePid is set on the page.

```
$config = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(Tx_Extbase_Configuration_ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
var_dump($config['persistence']['storagePid']);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, what are you trying to get. Snippet you provided gets without problems the storagePid set in constants for your extension, the same as this code from `setup.txt`:

```
plugin.tx_yourext {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_yourext.persistence.storagePid}
    }
}
```

if you have problems with getting your storagePid with provided snippet also can modify your `setup.txt` and make sure that the value will be also propagated into `settings` scope:

```
plugin.tx_yourext {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_yourext.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    settings {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_yourext.persistence.storagePid}
    }
}
```

then in your controller you can catch it with simpler code:

```
$myStoragePid = $this->settings['storagePid'];
```

if it will not work for you that means, you didn't set proper value in `Constants` for YourExt and/or didn't cleared the caches in the BE.

BTW: Maybe if you'll be more specific I could send better answer.